# Fire simulation in 2.82

Tags: physics

I made animation in 2.79 & I opened it in 2.82 to render. All effects work (dynamic paint, ocean, particles, soft body), but fire doesn't work. It doesn't even appear in preview window. Also, all fire settings were reset. I found answer how display fire, for this need to change Type of Domain to Replay. But Bake button disappeared.

How to bake fire simulation on Replay? Other types Modular & Final don't display anything even after baking. Or what to do so that fire is displayed & rendered in 2.82 Cycles (and preferably with settings from 2.79)?

Answer (score 1):

With blender 2.82 a new fluid simulation engine was introduced called Mantaflow. So that is the reason your old simulations are not working, you can try using a older blender version.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I didn't know about Mantaflow. I checked in 2.81a, fire was able to render as in 2.79. Only unfortunately Denoise node in this version of Blender works worse & blurs all details.
 And what does Mantaflow mean? What is its difference from previous engine?

Comment: Denoise in 2.81 works perfectly fine, make sure you are using the new denoise node based on the Intel denoiser.
First go to view layer properties and turn on denoising data and go to compositor and add denoiser and connect noisy image, denoising albedo and normal to the denoise node.

Comment: I do everything so how you said. But when I compared the same frame in 2.81 & 2.82, I saw difference. In 2.81 is more blurry.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to bake if you set your cache type to replay. You can simply hit the space and it will start baking in real-time(which means you can see what is happening in the viewport and make changes accordingly). You will have to set it to modular or final to bake. Note that your you can play with a better fps if you bake it with modular or final

Comment: In real-time it plays sooooo long. Even much longer than in 2.79. Modular & Final don't work. These types don't show anything even after baking.

Comment: what do you mean by so long

Comment: When click Play, then fps ~ 2-3. And this is with default settings. It's difficult to make any settings with such low fps.

Comment: you will have to pause to make changes. Also, you have to hit the bake button if you are using modular or final. note if you bring the resolution of smoke down you can bake faster even in replay

Comment: Modular & Final types don't work. Therefore, I can't bake simulation. And in Replay such low fps always. I created new file, added cube & Suzanne, made Domain & Flow from them & played animation. Fps ~ 3.

Comment: did you bring down the smoke resolution

Comment: OK, I made Resolution divisions: 6. FPS ~ 13-14. No, this clearly doesn't depend on it. Maybe need to include something in Preferences? I already don't know what to do, but smoke in 2.8 works disgustingly. Or maybe it's bug of 2.8?